# How do I uninstall softwares using C# or powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to uninstall a list of softwares silently, which I received from Windows Registry.
This has to be integrated in a WPF Application.
I have tried Cim, WMI, ManagementObjectSearcher for uninstalling as below

`Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_Product | Where {$_.Name -like \"{returnStr}\"} | Remove-CimInstance".Replace("{returnStr}", softwareName)`

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product WHERE Name = '" + ProgramName + "'");
foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
{
  if (mo["Name"].ToString() == ProgramName)
  {
    object hr = mo.InvokeMethod("Uninstall", null);
  }
}
```

Both these methods were unable to find the Software from the name that we got from Registry.
In ManagementObjectSearcher mos.Get() it throws Call Cancelled error.

Also tried the UninstallString from Registry which is also not working and I am getting options box for MsiExec.

Powershell script to uninstall these softwares also might help.

Comment: There is nothing WPF special here

Comment: Will https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msiexec#examples-4 work for you?

Comment: [Working with Software Installations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-software-installations)